# JMeter: Calling external classes and methods?

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I have a Java test project that I would like to import in my JMeter test so that I can call the existing methods in the test project. I did some research, and came to know that I can create a jar of my Java project, copy the jar into the JMETER_HOME/lib/ext folder, and then use the BeanShell Processor to call the external methods.

I am trying to use the existing test project, and call its methods to generate a JSON payload. 
I added a BeanShell PreProcessor, and did something like:

```
import com.qa.base.services.user.User;

User user = User.generateSimpleUser();
        user.setField("username", "testUsername");
        user.setField("password", "testPassword");

vars.put("requestJsonPayload", user.toString());
```

This does not seem to work, and I get an ERROR:

> ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import
>   com.qa.base.services.user.User'' : Typed variable declaration : Method
>   Invocation User.generateSimpleUser()

Anybody know how I can achieve what I am trying to do? Any suggestions, comments, links to tutorials, examples would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

**More Info:**

I am also using a BeanShell PostProcessor that gets the response payload of one of my requests, removes some fields in the payload, and constructs a new payload which I can send as a request payload for another request. The BeanShell PostProcessor works without any issues. I used JSONObject for this, and my code looks like:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
print(jsonString);
JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(jsonString);
responseJSON.remove("createTime");
responseJSON.remove("id");

vars.put("updatedJsonPayload",responseJSON.toString());
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you did check that the jar you exported really contains your compiled class, and you did restart JMeter after copying it in lib/ext, right?

Comment: Yes, the jar contains the class I need. I used maven to compile the jars so that it pulls all dependencies as well.

Comment: Maven will not pack your dependencies inside your jar with the rest of the classes. It will only pack them if you're building a war. Can you please paste the User class as well?

Comment: [link](http://www.milinovsky.at/jalbum/) there is the same question you had.

Comment: Can you show `User` class? (or main parts of it with method)

Answer (score 0):

Put the jar that contains "com.qa.base.services.user.User" and all its dependencies in jmeter/lib folder and it should work.